# printing a matrix adress instead of values | C

Tags: c

I wrote a code that tries to multiply two matrices and put them in another result matrix. The code is working (I think) but it prints a very strange output .. I think it has to do with one of the functions pointing to something diffrent than the values, not sure though.
I tried checking each function in separete, also inizialzing each matrix with {0}.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5
//#pragma warning(disable:4996)
//#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

void read_mat(int mat[][SIZE])
{
    int i, j, k = 0;
    char s[100]; // assign input str to 's'
    fgets(s,25,stdin); // recieving only the first 25 numbers
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            if (s[k] == '\0') { //if the string is just \0 -- the end of the string
                mat[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else { // is there are values in s
                if (s[k] != '0') { // binary matrix -- only 0 or 1
                    mat[i][j] = 1;
                    k++;
                }
                else {
                    mat[i][j] = 0;
                    ++k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void mult_mat(int mat_a[][SIZE], int mat_b[][SIZE], int result_mat[][SIZE])
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) {
                result_mat[i][j] += mat_a[i][k] * mat_b[k][j]; // by definition of matrix multiplication
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void print_mat(int mat[][SIZE])
{
    int i, j, k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%3d", &(mat[i][j])); // printing each value with a 3*space
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int mat_a[SIZE][SIZE] = {0}, mat_b[SIZE][SIZE] = {0}, result_mat[SIZE][SIZE] = {0}; // initializing matricies to {0}
    printf("Please Enter Values For Matrix 1\n");
    read_mat(mat_a);
    printf("Please Enter Values For Matrix 2\n");
    read_mat(mat_b);
    mult_mat(mat_a, mat_b, result_mat);
    printf("The First Matrix Is :- \n");
    print_mat(mat_a);
    printf("The Second Matrix Is :- \n");
    print_mat(mat_b);
    printf("The Resultant Matrix Is :- \n");
    print_mat(result_mat);
    return 0;
}
```

the outout I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnbvC.jpg)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

improve your print function

```
void print_mat(int mat[][SIZE])
{
    int i, j, k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            printf("(%3d), ", &(mat[i][j])); // printing each value with a 3*space
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```